# Pass parameters to node.js domain.on('error'...)

Tags: node.js, koa

I use `koa`, `domain` and `koa-respond`. 
I use `domain` because request sometime crashes and I want to **not** crash node.js.
My question is, `is it possible to cancel request from node.js domain?` I want to cancel request and show a response for user.

The below code hangs the request but **not** sending response (though node.js is not crashed):

```
const domain = require('domain');

export default {
  tryReq: async (ctx, next) => {
    try {
        const d = domain.create();
        const parsedData = await d.run(async () => {
          const MyLink = `http://thesite.com/${ctx.params.data}`;
          d.add(ctx);
          d.on('error', err => {
            try {
              ctx.throw(403, 'Crashing');
              d.dispose();
            } catch (er) {
              console.error('Error', er, ctx.params.data);
              d.dispose();
            }
          });
          const parsedDataValue = await callUrl(MyLink);
          return parsedDataValue;
        });
        return ctx.ok(parsedData);
    } catch (err) {
      ctx.internalServerError(err);
    }
  }
};
```